# TermRangeQuery in lucene for long values

Tags: lucene, range, byte, long-integer, epoch

I'm using **Lucene 8** and trying to perform a range query for epoch values (which are timestamps of my documents being indexed). However I've seen that lucene 8 supports only term-range query and this takes parameters bytesref instead of long. Can someone tell me if there is any alternative that takes long as input values and performs the range query or kindly let me know how to convert a long value to bytesref.

Below is my code ::

```
Term startTerm = new Term(OFFER_END_DATE_KEY, valueOf(Instant.now()));
Term endTerm   = new Term(OFFER_END_DATE_KEY, valueOf(Instant.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.YEARS)));
new TermRangeQuery(OFFER_END_DATE_KEY, startTerm, endTerm, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to use below construct:

```
TermRangeQuery.newStringRange(String field, String lowerTerm, String upperTerm, boolean includeLower, boolean includeUpper);
```

To use this convert the epoch timestamp to String value.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your `BytesRef` question directly, the `LongPoint` field type (https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongPoint.html) has a static method `pack` which does this.

It seems easier to use the `LongPoint` field at index time however, and query with `LongPoint.newRangeQuery(String field, long[] lowerValue, long[] upperValue)`.